# ¿Cómo quitar el azul que aparece cuando seleccionas una imagen?

Tags: html5, css, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, quisiera saber como puedo quitar el azul que aparece al seleccionar una imagen en Google Chrome, lo que estoy haciendo es un piano interactivo que cuando pulsas realiza la función del onclick que hace que suene, pero lo que pasa es que si pulso varias veces y rápido me lo muestra así y no se como quitarlo (solo pasa en GOOGLE CHROME)

Comment: Le di a aprobar una a una edición, pero la palabra `imagen` se escribe sin tilde, disculpas :P http://dle.rae.es/?id=KzwDY4y

Comment: @ArieCwHat Solucionado :P

Comment: Tienes toda la razón se me fue la cabeza, un saludo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `user-select: none` para impedir que el usuario pueda seleccionar la imagen y por lo tanto no aparezca en azul cuando la seleccionas.

Ejemplo:

```css
img{
   width: 300px;
   user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAARpAAAAJDMzZGRhNGMwLTU4YmMtNDdmZi1hMjU5LWIwYTViMjdlNWJmOQ.png">
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias :)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar css y agregarle una clase como esta:

```css
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

El contenido lo encontré en el sitio en ingles de stackoverflow, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css)

Comment: De lujo, muchas gracias :)